# AWS Policy Restrict Permission Based On Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I need to provide IAM role creation permission to a user but with a condition that if he does it only from some AWS service.
For example, if a user running cloudformation stack and attempting to create an IAM role, he should be allowed. if he manually creating role it should be denied. or if a person creating a codepipeline he should have permission to create the role.

Answer (score 1):

The concept you are looking for sounds like service-linked roles.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/using-service-linked-roles.html

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/introducing-an-easier-way-to-delegate-permissions-to-aws-services-service-linked-roles/

However, I don't think it is supported for CloudFormation or CodePipeline

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html

Comment: Thanks for your time Dude however I am looking for something else. Let me give you an example. When we create the policy we can add a condition that allows access only when the request is coming from certain IP addresses. I thought a condition can be added for the service name. let me know if it's possible.